# Network line switch-over in Oracle Data Guard

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, dataguard

We have a Primary database with a remote Standby which established using Oracle Data Guard. They can be syncing over a private Wireless Network and a Wired LAN (There are two options as network medium)

Is there any setting in Data Guard to handle network line failure? For example, I want to set wired LAN as main line and when it is not available data guard automatically switch to wireless network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can configure alternate locations.

You may have this now on the primary database:

```
log_archive_dest_1='location=use_db_recovery_file_dest' -- FRA for local archivelogs 
log_archive_dest_2='service=standby_TNS_wired_network ...'
```

And you can configure this:

```
log_archive_dest_1='location=use_db_recovery_file_dest' -- FRA for local archivelogs
log_archive_dest_2='service=standby_TNS_wired_network ... alternate=log_archive_dest_3'
log_archive_dest_3='service=standby_TNS_wireless_network ... alternate=log_archive_dest_2'
log_archive_dest_state_2=enable
log_archive_dest_state_3=alternate
```

[Example 17-3 Defining an Alternate Oracle Net Service Name to the Same Standby Database](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SBYDB/log_arch_dest_param.htm#GUID-88222D10-22FD-4F3B-BBE5-B59C8ABEC725__CHDDFHDI)

> ```
> LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_2='SERVICE=stby1_path1 MAX_FAILURE=1 ALTERNATE=LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_3 DB_UNIQUE_NAME=stdby1'
> LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_STATE_2=ENABLE
> LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_STATE_3=ALTERNATE
> LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_3='SERVICE=stby1_path2 DB_UNIQUE_NAME=stdby1'
> ```

Comment: Thank you, using this solution can I handle priority? I want when my wired LAN is available regardless of wireless network, the former one be my primary network medium.
Connection must be switched over wired LAN upon its availability.

Comment: @S0H31L This does the first part. By default, failed destinations are checked every 300 seconds for availability. You can change this in `log_archive_dest_n` parameter by setting `REOPEN` to the required value.